# How to copy original train defined variables into new train in anylogic train decouple

Tags: anylogic, decoupling

If we define a custom train agent in anylogic rail library and add some variables to that train agent,how we can keep data related to those new variables in new decoupled train when we use train decouple. Data (for example train code) that was assigned to original train, remains the same in remained train but does not exist anymore in new decoupled train which exits via out decouple port.

How we can save this data in new train?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the on exit (decoupled) action of the traindecouple element you have 2 variables that you can use: train1 and train2, where train1 is the original train that exits through the first port and train2 is the decoupled train that exits through the other port. Since train1 keeps the original info about the train, you have to the following for each of the variables you want to copy:

```
train2.var1=train1.var1;
train2.var2=train1.var2;
```

etc...

You can see the existence of these variables, if you hover over the little bulb that is on the left of the action field:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, but in version I use, there are no train1 and train2 variables in non of exits or enter fields. each of them has only train variable and refer to different trains, the train in exit refer to original and the train in exit (decoupled) refer to new train. now what should I do?

Comment: I updated the question for you to understand that train1 and train2 variables DO exist... read more about the light bulb here: http://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling

If they still don't exist.. update anylogic

Comment: Dear Felipe, it seems that the main problem is my anylogic version, but I solved it anyway. I created a temporarily train variable and saved pre-decouple train data in it and copy the parameter to new train in its exit action.

Comment: And one more thing, I would be really thankful if you consider a way of direct contact, such as e-mail or any other way.